# What is the Mac OSX version of NotifyAddrChange?

Tags: c, macos, networking

I want a function which will block until an interface is bound/unbound for OS X (i.e. the equivalent of Windows' `NotifyAddrChange`. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `SCNetworkReachability`, take a look at [the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html).

Note that you need to include `<SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>` to use it.

Comment: This is actually not the same thing. This api doesn't let me know the status of the individual adapters. Consider the following situation: you have 2 adapters both connected through different internet providers and one of the connections goes down. The endpoint is still reachable by the host, but you've lost a connection.

Comment: I think you can still know, as the callback (SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack) should be called when there's  a change in an interface, specifying which is it.

Comment: The callback proves the target and reachability flags, not the adapter.

Comment: If the answer doesn't satisfy you, it's fine if you don't accept and wait for a better one.

Comment: The problem is that I dont think that there is a better answer.